# Error: JOptionPane.showOptionDialog

Tags: java

Guys I've been working on my assignment, I only have 1 error. I don't have any idea to fix this so could you help me, or if you have suggestions just edit my code. The error was "The method showOptionDialog(Component, Object, String, int, int, Icon, Object[], Object) in the type JOptionPane is not applicable for the arguments (null, String, int, int, null, Object[], Object)"

Here's my code below

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FLABWORK3_ABUEL
{
  static Scanner Scan = new Scanner (System.in);
  public static void main(String[]  args)
  {
  String choice;
  String num1;
  String string;
  String Inverse;

  int choicee, num2, response, length;
  double squareroot;

  Object[] options = {"Yes", "No"};

  do {
      choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Main Menu" + 
  "\n 1. Square of a number" +
  "\n 2. Square root a number" +
  "\n 3. Cube of a number" +
  "\n 4. Length of number" +
  "\n 5. Inverse of a String");

      choicee = Integer.parseInt(choice);

      while (choicee > 5)
      {
          choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter only 1-5!");
      }

      if (choicee == 1)
      {
        num1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an number.");
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(num1);
        num2 = num2*num2 ;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The square of the number: " + num2);

    } else if (choicee == 2)
    {
        num1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number.");
        squareroot = Integer.parseInt(num1);
        squareroot = Math.sqrt(squareroot);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Square root is: " + squareroot);

    } else if (choicee == 3)
    {
        num1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number.");
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(num1);
        num2 = num2*(num2*num2);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The cube is: " + num2);

    } else if (choicee == 4) 
    {
        string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a sentence or a word.");
        length = string.length();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The length :  " + "\n" + length + "\n\n" +
          "is:" + string);

    }
    else if (choicee == 5)
    {
        string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a word.");
        length = string.length();
        for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
              Inverse = Inverse + string.charAt(i);
    }

        response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                  "Would you like to try again?",
                  JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                  JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null, options, options[0]);

  }
  while (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
```

}
}

Comment: try     response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "would you like to try again", "title",      JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

Comment: @BartHofma I tried that but it didn't work. I also tried to match the arguments still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the right number of arguments. Here's the structure for showOptionDialog:

```
showOptionDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message, String title, int optionType, int messageType, Icon icon, Object[] options, Object initialValue)
```

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

Comment: Thanks! The sytanx error was gone but another error appeared it says  Inverse = Inverse + string.charAt(i); The local varialble inverse may not be initialized